# Why won't the useEffect hook run and fetch data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, web-applications, axios

I am creating this simple news app with dotnet webapi and react. I want to fetch the news from my backend. The API is working fine, I have tested it, but somehow my useEffect won't run and I can't fetch the data. What am I doing wrong and what is the proper way of doing this? Any help will be appreciated!

Here's my app.js where the fetching should be working.

```
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';
import ArticleList from './/components/ArticleList.jsx';

function App() {
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('If it works, this should be shown!')
    axios.get('https://localhost:7112/News').then(response => {
      setArticles(response.data)
      console.log(articles)
    });
  },[]);


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ArticleList articles={articles}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import ArticleListItem from './ArticleListItem.jsx'

export default function ArticleList(articles) {
    
    return (
        <>
            {articles && articles.map(article => (<ArticleListItem key={article.title} article={article} />
        ))}
        </>
    )
}
```

There's the component which throws error: articles.map is not a function.

Comment: It should be `import ArticleList from './components/ArticleList.jsx';` with one slash not `import ArticleList from './/components/ArticleList.jsx';` with two slashs.

Comment: It doesn't help my actual problem, useEffect still not running, but thanks for pointing out!

Comment: is there anything like an error or something shown in the console ?

Comment: did you import :  `import {useEffect} from 'react'`

Comment: Oh yes @monim it didn't copy it, but I have the imports right!

Comment: @monim the only error that shows up in the console is articles.map is not a function, in the ArticlesList component. That error occurs when map() is called on something non-array, and the articles variable would be array if the useEffect hook worked and fetched me the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error does not come from `useEffect` neither tha `App` component . But **ArticleList** it self when you pass `articles` as a `props` to ArticleList component  and before mapping it you have to check if you have articles first :
You can do something like this :

```
{props.articles && props.articles.map(...)
```

Comment: If you didn't understand what I mean add you **ArticleList**  i'll  explain iit to you

Comment: Added ArticleList code to the original question. How can I fix it? @monim

Comment: Okay, got pass that problem and the next occured. Check out my new question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73882210/how-can-i-access-the-values-of-the-props-in-my-component . A new problem Objects are not valid as a React child occured in the component I am passing the props ahead to. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Okay i'll see it

Answer (score 0):

You need to check articles to render Loading or ArticleList

```
{articles && <ArticleList articles={articles}/>}
```

or you set initial value for articles state:

```
const [articles, setArticles] = useState([])
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it still doesn't work. The problem is the useEffect hook not running when the site is loaded. The console.log("If it work, this should show up!") doesn't show up in the console. I also have a check at my API that would tell if it received a request.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using webstorm and for some reason it was not printing the useEffect console logs in my webstorm terminal, when I checked the logs in the browser console everything was getting printed in the logs